# Limiting the number of checkboxes selected by user

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

i have a page on there.i have number of check boxes.i want user to select on three not more than that and one check box has the value "NOT interested ",if user click on this all other check box must has to disabled.for that i tried javascript.
this is what i tried

```
function chkcontrol(j) {
            var total = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < document.form1.user[portal_choice].length; i++) {
                if (document.form1.user[portal_choice][i].checked) {
                    total = total + 1;
                }
                if (total > 3) {
                    alert("Please Select only three")
                    document.form1.user[portal_choice][j].checked = false;
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
```

i getting error in the portal_choice variable.That is mapped with the database column name and user is my table name.
help me to do that and suggest me to disabling the checkbox when user click on "NOT INTERSTED".and its not rail 3.0

thanks pal for consideration.........

Comment: This has little to do with Ruby. This is entirely JS.

Answer (score 1):

Using this syntax `document.form1.user[portal_choice]`, you are telling Javascript that you want the form called 'form1' and from that form, get the elements called 'user', and look at the one with an index that is contained in the (javascript) variable 'portal_choice'. That variable is not defined in your function.

I am not familiar with Ruby, but from some quick reading, it looks like you can refer to Ruby variables directly in html, but not in Javascript. I think you have to wrap it with `<%= %>` like so:

```
document.form1.user[<%= portal_choice %>].length
```

However, I don't see why you would use a Ruby variable here. You just want to iterate through all of the checkboxes, right? I don't think checkbox elements are ever 2-dimensional arrays, as in

```
document.form1.user[portal_choice][i]
```

I think you really just want to do this:

```
function chkcontrol(j) {
            var total = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < document.form1.user.length; i++) {
                if (document.form1.user[i].checked) {
                    total = total + 1;
                }
                if (total > 3) {
                    alert("Please Select only three")
                    document.form1.user[j].checked = false;
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
```

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cordesmj/LhBsa/14/)